# Installing subversion under /apps other than /var/www/ is not working. Centos Linux version

Tags: svn, installation, centos

I m installing the subversion for the 1st time and have a lot ofquestions. the svn is under /var/www/svn and which is on rot (/) has only 50 Gb of space. Our devlopers might need lot of space than 50GB. i m trying to create repositoies under /apps ( or install svn under /apps by modifying the subversion.conf file but when i access the page it is saying forbidden. seems like apache can only access svn if it is under /var/www/. Can someone help me in solving this issue. as my /apps Filesystem has 1TB of space.and is a separate mount to /.

Comment: you can install it anywhere. Just use svnadmin to create the repository under /apps. Installation of subversion is best left to the OS

Comment: Hi Somesh. I did create a repository saying svn ( using svnadmin). and I also had the below two lines in the httpd.conf file.
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
#DocumentRoot "/apps/SVNREPOS/svn"
.I also edited the subversion.conf file to point to /apps/SVNREPOS/svn but i get the forbidden error and permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

In the httpd.conf file your Document Root Section probally says

```
<Directory "/var/www">
```

Also you can give apache ownership of that directory but only if such is placed in the document root. (If I understand you this may not work for you)

```
chown -R apache.apache /apps
```

Apache can access items outside the root but that is soemthing I am not familiar with and you can look into the apache [Alias](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/apache-403-access-denied-outside-of-document-root-365455/)

**EDIT**
As the comment under your OP says SVNADMIN should be able to create the repo and you should be able to hit it.

```
mkdir /app/svn
svnadmin create /app/svn/testrepository
chown svn:svn -R /app/svn
```

Subversion also is very nice about keeping space low since it only stores revisions to projects instead or brand new versions each time.

**EDIT**
[Setup Walkthrough - Posted in comments](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-svn-subversion-server-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

Comment: I initially changed the httpd.conf file to /apps . and also gave the permission to apache for /apps/ . It did not change anything.

Comment: i had these lines earlier
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
#DocumentRoot "/apps/SVNREPOS/svn"

Comment: Document Root can be changed on the DocumentRoot Line. Below in the config there is a setting about features. It noted that it should be set to what DocumentRoot is. As the comment under your post mentioned it should work without this. (I believe)

Comment: I actually comment the /apps in the DocumentRoot after i got the 403 Forbidden error. I was just saying that i tried that option. Shold this step work
chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /apps/SVNREPOS/svn ?

Comment: I am unsure if chcon will work on the fresh instance. I know a while ago I used http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-svn-subversion-server-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ to help setup subversion

Comment: I meant the Directory variable in httpd.conf file should be /apps. Which i think i changed it and restarted the httpd service.

Comment: DocumentRoot "/apps"
<Directory "/apps"
Are these values Right in the httpd.conf file ?

Comment: Shouild i also change the subversion.conf file. With the value SVNParentpath to be /apps?

Comment: @user2676080 If you set the DocumentRoot to /apps that is just where apache is going to look. It should be fine as long as other stuff isnt in the oldDir Root. Using SVNParentPath should list all repos under that directory. In your case /apps